# Remove a checkbox and its corresponding list tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to remove an input and its list tag from an unordered list using jquery or javascript. I click a button to make an ajax call to get which input to remove, and remove the checkbox based on the data from the ajax call. The ul is a bootstrap list group

html file

```
<ul class="list-group" id="item_list">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input me-1" name="item" type="checkbox" value="item">item
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I tried

main.js

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#item_list :checkbox[value=' + data['item_to_del'] + ']').remove();
}
```

This only removes the checkbox, and the input label and the list tag is still there, so there's an empty box with the label still in the ul. How do I remove the entire list tag?

Comment: It's a *listitem* tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After finding the `<input>`, navigate up to its parent to remove both the `<li>` and its children:

```
$('#item_list :checkbox[value=' + data['item_to_del'] + ']')
  .parent()
  .remove();
```